# Comparing OffsetDateTime to Timestamp in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, timestamp, scalatest

I'm quite new in Scala world

In my Scala tests I have java.time.OffsetDateTime and java.sql.Timestamp

```
offsetDateTimeValue shouldBe timestampValue
```

Result:

```
Expected :2019-06-20T16:19:57.988Z
Actual   :2019-06-20 16:19:57.988
```

Any ideas? I was thinking to implement a custom matcher but got stuck with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom matcher since I needed it in many tests

```
def beTheSameDate(right: OffsetDateTime) = DateTestMatcher(right)

case class DateTestMatcher(right: OffsetDateTime) extends Matcher[Timestamp] {
  override def apply(left: Timestamp): MatchResult = {
    val areEqual = left.toLocalDateTime == right.toLocalDateTime
    MatchResult(areEqual, "Dates are not equal", "Dates are equal")
  }
```

And then

```
timestampValue should beTheSameDate(offsetDateTimeValue)
```

Comment: I also have comparisons between Option[Timestamp] and Option[OffsetDateTime] so I cant use that implicit. I overloaded beTheSameDate method and it works as a charm

Answer (score 3):

Try converting them both to a `Long` value like so

```
val expected = OffsetDateTime.parse(offsetDateTimeValue, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME).toInstant.toEpochMilli
val actual = timestampValue.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli
expected shouldBe actual
```

Comment: timestampValue.toInstant takes no parametes in my scala version (2.12.7)

Comment: result = false
I converted both to LocalDateTime and it works

Answer (score 2):

Custom equality solution -

```
implicit val timeEquality : Equality[OffsetDateTime] = (a: OffsetDateTime, b: Any) => b match {
  case timestamp: Timestamp => a.toInstant == timestamp.toInstant // can also go via epoch milliseconds as per Mario's solution
  case other => a == other
}

val instant = Instant.now()
val offset = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"))
val timestamp = Timestamp.from(instant)

offset shouldEqual timestamp // test passes
```

Using `equal`/`shouldEqual` instead of `be` allows you to customize the equality used by the matcher via implementing `Equality` and passing that as an implicit parameter. If you don't like the implicit, you can also pass it explicitly:

```
val timesBeingEqual: Equality[OffsetDateTime] = ...
(offset shouldEqual timestamp)(decided by timesBeingEqual)
```

If you have a bunch of time-related tests, this approach saves you the need to convert every time. The main downside is that you apparently can't selectively override equality only in the case where the thing you're comparing with is a timestamp, and that if you want to do the comparison the other way around you'll also have to implement an `Equality[Timestamp]`.